# Can't signature my LIbGDX Application

Tags: java, android, libgdx, apk, sign

I copied a Project from github and changed a few things in there. Now I tried to generate a signed APK of it, but it doesn't work, because I can't choose a selection field. Perhaps you can better imagine what I mean if you see the picture of the Field where I want to generate the APK.
What is the reason for that it doesn't work? And how can I solve my Problem?

Here is the image:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TdPL.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you've some older version of [android gradle plugin](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html), updating to latest version may solve your issue.

There is `buildscript` section inside root `build.gradle` file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {  
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'    // <- update version  
    }
}
```

Refresh all gradle projects.

---

According to developers [guide](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0.html#apk_signature_v2)

APK Signature Scheme v2 offers:

1. Faster app install times
2. More protection against unauthorized alterations to APK files.

It is **recommended** to use APK Signature Scheme **v2** but is **not mandatory**.

> Although we recommend applying APK Signature Scheme v2 to your app,
>   this new scheme is not mandatory. If your app doesn't build properly
>   when using APK Signature Scheme v2, you can disable the new scheme.